# Dependency Injection with configuration in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core

I am trying to inject dependency by getting configuration in class in .net core project. The class where I am trying to inject dependency is in another project. But somehow I am not able to get the values from config file in injected dependency.
Below is my code

In below DBContext I need to obtain value from configuration, where i have used DI of DBConfiguration class.

```
public class DBContext : DbContext
    {
        private readonly DBConfiguration _dBConfiguration;

        public DBContext(DBConfiguration dBConfiguration)
        {
            _dBConfiguration = dBConfiguration;
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_dBConfiguration.ConnectionString);
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
```

And my StartUp.cs file in web api

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddScoped<DBConfiguration>();

            services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer().AddDbContext<DBContext>();

            services.AddOptions();

            services.Configure<DBConfiguration>(Configuration.GetSection("DBConfiguration"));

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        }
```

and my appsettings.json file

```
{
  "DBConfiguration": {


         "ConnectionString": "Server=myserver;Database=BaseProjectDB;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
         "ApplicationName": "WebAPI"


  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Any help on this appreciated !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be using DBConfigurationOptions in your StartUp file, while you're injecting DBConfiguration in your DBContext.

This is how I currently use my configuration:

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        _configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<DBConfigurationOptions>(_configuration.GetSection("DBConfiguration"));
    }
}
```

and then it's injected as:

```
public class DBContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly DBConfigurationOptions _dBConfiguration;

    public DBContext(IOptions<DBConfigurationOptions> dBConfiguration)
    {
        _dBConfiguration = dBConfiguration.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah.. It just the options I was trying to use it... as someone has suggested on the net to use array thing.. i already tried with DBConfiguration also.. but in that case it also come null

Comment: I'm not entirely certain (it's been a while since I've set up something like this and I haven't used Entity Framework in forever), but maybe you should move the configuration in your startup above the addition of Sql Server.
Also, I'll edit my answer with an example of how we use the configuration, as that might be of use.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you configure the db directly in the place you also have the configuration?
In your DBContext class (btw you should probably choose a better name for that) you just need to expose a constructor like this, no need for overriding OnConfiguring or anything like that.

This class can be in any assembly you want.

```
class DBContext : DbContext
{
    public DBContext(DbContextOptions<DBContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

For the configuration you can just use the built in optionsBuilder-action (place inside the `ConfigureServices` method):

```
services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
    .AddDbContext<DBContext>(optionsBuilder =>
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
            Configuration.GetSection("DBConfiguration").Get<DBConfiguration>().ConnectionString)
    );
```

Currently the way you get the configuration can definitely be improved. For example you could do something like this:

```
var DBConfig = Configuration.GetSection("DBConfiguration").Get<DBConfiguration>();
services.AddSingleton(DBConfig);// <- now you can inject that if you want but it's not necessary

// now we don't need to get the config here
services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
    .AddDbContext<DBContext>(optionsBuilder =>
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(DBConfig.ConnectionString)
    );
```

There are some other things you might want to improve like better naming for `DBContext` and not overriding members you don't have a specific implementation for (like you did with `OnModelCreating`).

Also for a next time you should include all the classes that aren't part of some sort of public API like your `DBConfiguration` class.

Comment: Thanks for the help ! The reason I am doing like this as I am trying to make DAL which will have feasible common functionalities already available so i can use the same DAL in new project as well

Answer (score 0):

To receive the configuration, you have to modify the signature of your constructor in `DBContext` from

```
public DBContext(DBConfiguration dBConfiguration)
```

to

```
public DBContext(IOptions<DBConfiguration> dBConfiguration)
```

to receive the option properly (don't forget to add the namespace `Microsoft.Extensions.Options`).

Additionally, you need to define the `DBConfiguration` class somewhere with the properties you have in your configuration file.

Comment: But we cant use this without IOptions interface ?

Comment: I don't think so. If you add the options to the service collection via `services.Configure` you receive them via `IOptions`interface. That's the way it is designed.